# ¿como mostrar una foto a partir de un texto?

Tags: javascript, c#, css

En el siguiente código, en la línea `$("<td>").text(row.img)` quiero mostrar una imagen, he puesto href y no me hace ninguna referencia, ¿alguna idea? Saludos

```
AjaxPost("../Tienda", JSON.stringify(request),
    function (response) {
        $(".modal-body").LoadingOverlay("hide");
        if (response.estado) {
            $.each(response.objeto, function (i, row) {
                    $("<tr>").append(
                        $("<td>").append(
                            $("<button>").addClass("btn btn-sm btn-primary ml-2").append(
                                $("<i>").addClass("fa fa-check").attr({"aria-hidden":"true"})
                            ).data("producto", row)
                        ),
                        $("<td>").text(row.oProducto.Codigo),
                        $("<td>").text(row.oProducto.Nombre),
                        $("<td>").text(row.oProducto.Descripcion),
                        $("<td>").text(row.Stock),
                        $("<td>").text(row.img)
                    ).appendTo("#tbProducto tbody");
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

Según entiendo, lo que quieres es que dentro del  se muestre una imagen; y en el campo row.img tienes la ruta de la imagen verdad?
siguiendo esta premisa, podrias hacer lo siguiente:

```
$("<td>").append(`<img src="${row.img}">`)
```

Esto, si es que te entendí correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Una sugerencia para mostrar una imagen en la tabla es utilizar el método [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) de jQuery.
Lo que hace .attr() es manipular los atributos HTML, como src, href y target.

```
$("<td>").text(row.img).attr("src", row.img);
```

Otra forma de aplicarlo:

```
$("<img>").attr("src", row.img).appendTo("td");
```

De esta manera, estableciendo un valor específico para los atributos de los elementos HTML.